# Profile pics now showing as questions marks

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Our canvas app just started showing questions marks for the profile pictures in Chrome. we use this call https://graph.facebook.com/{fbid}/picture?type=small to get the images. It just started happening today.

Any thoughts to what is going on?

Comment: Facebook is looking into it.  There might be a bug in the graph endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue. It is related to the latest version of the webplayer plugin having an issue with www http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/www-throws-failed-downloading-with-webplayer-4-dot-3-5